# PHP array asort accented character

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a page with a `SELECT` tag proposing to choose between multiple countries.
The `SELECT` options are dynamically generated, a SQL query select all the countries from the database, not sorted, and add them into an array.
Then, I use asort to sort the array and propose the `SELECT`.
It works as long as there isn't accented characters, and accented character options are sorted after everything.

Check it on the page : http://worldisbeautiful.net/partager/?force_language=fr

- make sure *force_language=fr* is on, otherwise it will be english by
  default
- check the source code, you'll see 3 commented tests I made with the results

I tried, with no luck, solutions proposed on these questions :

- [Sort an array with special characters in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649473/sort-an-array-with-special-characters-in-php?rq=1)
- [Sorting array with collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571273/sorting-array-with-collation?rq=1)
- [How to sort an array considering localization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273165/how-to-sort-an-array-considering-localization)

For information, i receive sorted country data from databases but in english, then i localize them in french and due to complete name change it's unsorted (ie in french, united stats is états-unis).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array considering localization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10273165/how-to-sort-an-array-considering-localization)

Comment: I assume you can not do the sorting in the database? (that would be the easiest way, as you have more control over how to sort there)

Comment: I actually do, but countries are stored in english and when they are localized, the order change (ie in french, "united states" is "états-unis").

Comment: Right. The duplicate above should help?

Comment: Nope, tried it, no luck.

Comment: There is also something weird, both `setlocale` and `collator` possible solutions show a completly unsorted array whereas `asort` all alone still sort unaccented countries. I don't understand what's going on :/

Comment: Are you working with UTF-8 data?

Comment: Yes I do use UTF8. I'm considering to stop searching and go with a workaround like country localization in my database, this will resolve sorting issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort an array with special characters in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10649473/sort-an-array-with-special-characters-in-php)

Comment: Please post actual PHP code of what you tried and that indeed wouldn't sort right - "no luck" is too vague to help any further, while pinpointing could turn out your system just hasn't any French localization (for collations and such).

Comment: You are 6 years late AmigoJack ;)